# Python - Performance when adding many dicts of lists to a persistent master dict

Tags: python, list, performance, dictionary

I have a dictionary "update" algorithm that I suspect is not the most efficient way.  As I run my program and continuously add a new dictionary to my existing dictionary, the performance slows down significantly over time.  I'd like to find a more performant way.

## My dictionary update operation

I have a loop where each iteration processes a file, and results in a "dict of lists of dicts".  Each main dict key has a list value, the items of which are themselves dicts, of which there can be multiple.  In this example, the list belonging to B has two dicts in it.  I might process the first file and get this result:

```
{'A': [{'filename': 6311, 'id': 6634, 'num_transactions': 4969, 'total': 7808}], 
 'B': [{'filename': 6311, 'id': 3578, 'type': 8268, 'diameter': 2281, 'width': 4617}, 
       {'filename': 6311, 'id': 2289, 'type': 1553, 'diameter': 4104, 'width': 8725}]}
```

Then I might process another file and get this:

```
{'C': [{'filename': 7775, 'id': 177, 'count': 6139, 'needed': 7905}], 
 'B': [{'filename': 7775, 'id': 7540, 'type': 9854, 'diameter': 3729, 'width': 9145}, 
       {'filename': 7775, 'id': 27, 'type': 2380, 'diameter': 7209, 'width': 6023}]}
```

I then combine these dicts into a master dict where I continuously combine the lists based on their key value.  The combination of the above two dicts would result in (order here is arbitrary, but sorted for readability):

```
{'A': [{'filename': 6311, 'id': 6634, 'num_transactions': 4969, 'total': 7808}], 
 'B': [{'filename': 6311, 'id': 3578, 'type': 8268, 'diameter': 2281, 'width': 4617}, 
       {'filename': 6311, 'id': 2289, 'type': 1553, 'diameter': 4104, 'width': 8725}, 
       {'filename': 7775, 'id': 7540, 'type': 9854, 'diameter': 3729, 'width': 9145}, 
       {'filename': 7775, 'id': 27, 'type': 2380, 'diameter': 7209, 'width': 6023}], 
 'C': [{'filename': 7775, 'id': 177, 'count': 6139, 'needed': 7905}]}
```

Note that I **must** have a final master_dict that contains the combined data across all of my dictionaries, this is non-negotiable.

## Algorithm and Performance

Below is a complete program to generate random `cur_dicts` and continuously add their results to the `master_dict`.  The function `add_to_master_dict()` represents my update algorithm.

```
import random
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
random.seed(0)

a_keys = ['id', 'num_transactions', 'total']
b_keys = ['id', 'type', 'diameter', 'width']
c_keys = ['id', 'count', 'needed']
key_dict = {'A':a_keys, 'B':b_keys, 'C':c_keys}

def generate_cur_dict(key_dict):
    cur_dict = {}
    filename_int = random.randint(0, 10000)

    for main in random.sample(key_dict.keys(), 
                              random.randint(1, len(key_dict.keys()))):
        cur_dict[main] = []

        num_rows = random.choice([1, 1, random.randint(1, 3)])
        for _ in range(num_rows):
            temp_dict = {}
            temp_dict['filename'] = filename_int
            for k in key_dict[main]:
                temp_dict[k] = random.randint(0, 10000)

            cur_dict[main].append(temp_dict)

    return cur_dict

# Hacky use of variable scope by assuming existence of cur/master_dict, 
# but easiest way to pass to timeit
def add_to_master_dict():
    if not master_dict:   # master_dict is empty
        master_dict.update(cur_dict)
    else:
        for k in cur_dict.keys():
            if k in master_dict:
                # In case of None value rather than a list
                if cur_dict[k] is None:
                    continue
                else:
                    # Combine the two lists based on key
                    master_dict[k] = master_dict[k] + cur_dict[k]
            else:
                # If key not in master dict, just add the cur_dict value to the 
                # master_dict
                master_dict[k] = cur_dict[k]

master_dict = {}           
times = []
for i in range(50001):
    cur_dict = generate_cur_dict(key_dict)
    times.append(timeit.timeit(add_to_master_dict, number=1))
    # Easy visual way to see how much it slows down over time
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        print(i)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(times)
```

[image]

I know this isn't the most elegant way to use timeit - I'm not taking averages of execution, so there's a lot of variation - but I'm just trying to demo the concept.  It should be clear that if you run this for any significant number of iterations, `add_to_master_dict()` gets bogged down quite a bit, so I'm likely looking at exponential growth here for my updates.

Any suggestions for how I might perform my update operation in a way that (hopefully) achieves linear time?  I've been able to find dict/list update algorithms that perform well in simple cases, but nothing for my dict of lists use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
master_dict[k] = master_dict[k] + cur_dict[k]
```

Creates a new list every time it's executed.  Extending the existing list

```
master_dict[k] += cur_dict[k]
```

is much faster.  On my machine the execution time went from 1 min 46.857 seconds to 8.027 seconds.

I'm not an expert, but I suspect both versions of the code run in roughly<sup>*</sup> linear time.  However in the original code a new list of length n + k must be constructed for each execution of the line, whereas in the improved version an existing list is extended by k elements, which requires less memory allocation and object construction.

<sup>*</sup> Extending a list runs in *amortized* linear time - see https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Ah, I was overcomplicating - while I'm dealing with a "dict of lists of dicts", it's still ultimately just adding a list to an existing list, and there the answer is clear.   Also appreciate the clarification on the big-O execution.